# How to determine object type without raising an exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm refactoring some older code that uses `HttpClient` by inheriting from `WebRequestHandler` and doing:

```
public class ClientRequestHandler : WebRequestHandler
{
    public ClientRequestHandler()
    { }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(async task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    var nex = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<NotFoundException>();
                    throw nex;
                }

                else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
                {
                    var ex1 = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeException>();
                    throw ex1;

                    var ex2 = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OtherException>().Result;
                    throw ex2;
                }

                return response;
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The issue is the following block of code:

```
var ex1 = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeException>();
throw ex1;

var ex2 = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OtherException>().Result;
throw ex2;
```

I can wrap individual reads into `try catch` or first the content as a string, cast object and then check the type with either `typeof` or `is`. So it will look something like this:

```
var o = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result as object;

if (o is SomeException)
    throw (SomeException)o;
else if (o is OtherException)
    throw (OtherException)o;
```

Is there a cleaner way to determine what the content is and just switch to the correct instance?

Comment: Just wondering, but the exception is from an external system. Why would you want to deserialize is and not just throw your own exception?

Comment: @Stefan Because as in the case of `Conflict`, the content can be different exceptions

Comment: I understand, but alternatively, you could throw a custom exception, and put in the request's content as payload / string. That way you're more in control. Besides; external exceptions are not always stable - so, if you receive an unexpected one - you need to alter the code to cope with it. Just giving you a heads-up there. It might make things easier.

Comment: @Stefan I understand your reasoning. The exceptions are from separate internal system. However, implementing your suggestion requires much more time.

Comment: No need 'if'. Just do `throw (Exception)o;`